# ubuntu 16.04 network setting, why is my /etc/network/interfaces file so simple(settings only for lo)?

Tags: networking, dhcp

In https://geek-university.com/linux/configure-dhcp-client-on-ubuntu/, the /etc/network/interfaces file contains dhcp setting for eth0. But my 16.04 machine contains just contains below 4 lines.

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
dns-nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Why doesn't it contain information for my normal ethernet ports? (I am using port enp6s0. see below.)
My network setting is like this.

```
ckim@chan-ubuntu:$ ifconfig -a
enp6s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 2c:fd:a1:c7:1a:61  
          inet addr:129.254.31.181  Bcast:129.254.31.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::c527:96a9:2fd4:c09/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:62750912 errors:0 dropped:4956142 overruns:3 frame:0
          TX packets:17471237 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:30845857530 (30.8 GB)  TX bytes:10590589301 (10.5 GB)
          Memory:90200000-9027ffff 

enp7s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 2c:fd:a1:c7:1a:60  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Memory:90100000-9017ffff 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:14231 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:14231 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:3649045 (3.6 MB)  TX bytes:3649045 (3.6 MB)
```

And I tried to change the network setting by 'Applications-Settings-Network Connections' menu, but the interface was not editable for me(dimmed), maybe only superuser can change it. How can I use it?
ADD : I found I can use the settings GUI tool using console. (I was doing it on vnc), but I'm still curious if I can do it on vnc using gui tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is actually normal**.

The `interfaces` file is one of many ways to configure a network when a machine starts, yet it is not a "must have" method. consider it as a general Linux method, that is natively supported and common for Linux-based operating systems.

Many Linux-based operating systems also support other tools and methods of configuring your network, and tend **not to use** the `interfaces` file.
For example: by default your Ubuntu desktop uses [Network Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetworkManager) to manage network connections automatically and dynamically.

The Ubuntu Network Manager app is a package commonly installed as part of your base OS.

You may also manually install it using:

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager
```

This also let's you purge the package and use any other application of your choice, and even the `interfaces` file itself.

Further reading and documentation:

[Ubuntu - NetworkManager](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkManager)

Comment: that clearly explained it. thank you!